# Use conditional type as return type doesn't work correctly

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I want to get a string based on the type of the input parameter of a function `toTypeString` as follows:

```js
function toTypeString<T extends string | number>(x: T): T extends string ? "S" : T extends number ? "N": never {
  if (typeof x === 'string') return 'S';
  if (typeof x === 'number') return 'N';
  throw new Error(`unexpected value: ${x}`);
}
```

It works, but doesn't compile with the following error:

```
Type '"S"' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? "S" : T extends number ? "N" : never'.
Type '"N"' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? "S" : T extends number ? "N" : never'.
```

([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOAVAngBwKYGUoBOMYA5gDyqLYAeU2YAJgM6JOHEmIA+iYIAtgCNsBAHwAKagC5EqAJQzKNOoxZsipRAH5EAIly7EiqrXrNeA4QW16AcrplhsANxGIA3gFgAUIkQxgRHEoLGw4QOpEAF4YxABydQ44uUQCbCgQAiQ43DiAbh8-AKCQnHDESJio+L4hEWTU9Mzs23zC5AALAjgAd15sPoBRAm6CcQADcBocaGwGRGcAQwAbEGwZABJ3agBfcbkC7x2fIA))

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Typescript does control-flow type narrowing on regular variables, but not on type variables like your T. So this can't work. https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/chapters/narrowing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use function overloading here:

```
function toTypeString<T extends string | number>(x: T): T extends string ? "S" : T extends number ? "N": never
function toTypeString(x: string | number): "S" | "N" {
  if (typeof x === 'string') return 'S';
  if (typeof x === 'number') return 'N';
  throw new Error(`unexpected value: ${x}`);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQARyQFQJ4AcCmAynAE4JQDmAPJqvgB5z5QAmAzqm6eRagD6ooEALYAjfCQB8ACnoAuVJgCUC2gyasOXMpVQB+VACJCh1KrqNm7QSPEl9RgHKGFUfADcJoSLEQp0WHhE3JSyCto8-DZiEipGJlGGzqgA3qCoqAhgqNJwQUjZ9KgAvKWoAOQRlOVKqCT4cBAkaOWE5QDc6ZnZufmFJWXlQjEkNXUNTS2OHV1wABYkSADugvgrAKIkiyTSAAbQDATw+Cyo7gCGADYQ+AoAJCn0AL67Sp0gT6CgGDgExDoUaQABiU30CfxCgMMQMMSiAA)